# Number guessing "game" does not work on correct intput for 2+2 = 4

Tags: python-3.x

I keep failing to get the Correct answer to print.

```
guess = input("what is 2 + 2 ")
tries = 0

while guess != 4 and tries < 50:
    input ("try again ")
    tries + 1
if guess == 4:
    print("Correct")
else:
    print("Wrong")
```

Comment: change to `guess = int(input("what is 2 + 2 "))`

Comment: `input()` returns a string.  `"4" != 4`.

Comment: Also, `tries += 1` .

Comment: @DevangSanghani thanks it helped, but now the answer works only on the first try.

Comment: `guess = int(input("try again "))` - needs to be added. This will update the guess to be checked each time.

Comment: @DevangSanghani Thanks again, really appreciate it.