# Can't enter any guesses in this guessing game made in python

Tags: python

I am a beginner in Python and currently learning how to code in it. I made my first guessing game in Python.

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZWb8u.png)

Normally, I should be able to enter the guess. But I cannot enter any guesses in it. It's  prompting me that I'm out of guesses. Please help.

**Original Code**

```
guess_limit = 3
out_of_guesses = True

while guess != secret_word and not (out_of_guesses):
    if guess_count < guess_limit:
        guess = input("Enter guess: ")
        guess_count += 1
    else:
        out_of_guesses = False

if out_of_guesses:
    print("Out Of Guesses, You Lose! ")
else:
    print("You win!")`enter code here`
```

**Output**

C:\Users\hites\PycharmProjects\Test\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/hites/PycharmProjects/Test/app.py
Out Of Guesses, You Lose!

Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71572356/number-guessing-game-does-not-work-on-correct-intput-for-22-4

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: What is the `secret_word `? You are not accepting the guess before entering the while loop. `guess_count` is also not initialized with some value .

Comment: `secret_word` and `guess_count` are not defined. What are they?

Comment: You're setting `out_of_guesses` to `True` when it should be `False`, and vice versa

Answer (score 1):

Show the full code: we don't know what `guess_count` or `secret_word` is.

Without those, no one can really help you.

I made up `guess_count` and `secret_word`, to get the following (working) code:

```
guess_limit = 3
out_of_guesses = False

secret_word = 'kite' # put the secret word here
guess_count = 1

guess = input("Enter guess: ").lower()

while guess != secret_word and not (out_of_guesses):
    if guess_count < guess_limit:
        guess = input("Enter guess: ").lower()
        guess_count += 1
    else:
        out_of_guesses = True

if out_of_guesses:
    print("Out Of Guesses, You Lose! ")
else:
    print("You win!")
```

That was based on what I *thought* you were doing in the other lines of code (the part you haven't shown), though.
So, I reconstructed your code after adding other lines. I used `random.choice()` for getting `secret_word`.

Here it is, completed:

```
from random import choice

guess_limit = 3
out_of_guesses = False

guess_count = 1

secret_word = choice(['password','kite','name','foul','wire','name','locker','computer','mud','wolf','fox','pliers','piano','chair','monk'])

guess = input("Enter guess: ").lower()

while guess != secret_word and not out_of_guesses:
    if guess_count < guess_limit:
        guess = input("Enter guess: ").lower()
        guess_count += 1
        out_of_guesses = False
    else:
        out_of_guesses = True

if out_of_guesses:
    print("Out Of Guesses, You Lose! ")
else:
    print("You win!")
```

Also, you had all your booleans mixed up, with weird parts in your code.

At this point, though, this answer is mostly based on *guesswork* about what you're trying to do.

Still, I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You could solve it this way:

```
guess_limit = 3
guess_count = 1
out_of_guesses = True
secret_word = "Secret Word"
guess = input("Enter guess: ")

while guess != secret_word and out_of_guesses:
    if guess_count < guess_limit:
        guess = input("Enter guess: ")
        guess_count += 1
    else:
        out_of_guesses = False

if not out_of_guesses:
    print("Out Of Guesses, You Lose! ")
else:
    print("You win!")
```

Result:

```
Enter guess: Attempt1
Enter guess: Attempt2
Enter guess: Attempt3
Out Of Guesses, You Lose!

Enter guess: Secret Word
You win!
```